# Library not found -lAdIdAccess ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

Today when i have started compiling the code i am getting the folloing error
I have tried the other option like, setting the liker flag, framework search path,

```
ld: library not found for -lAdIdAccess
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I have updated my answer .may be it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.

Comment: Or easier still add it via *Linked Frameworks and Libraries* section on the *General* tab of the target's build settings.

Answer (score 0):

-lAdIdAccess is a part of Google Analytics SDK.

Don't forget to add a path to the SDK in Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths. Select "recursive" if the SDK is in a subfolder.